# Retrieving Facebook page conversation

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to retrieve Facebook page conversation content but the response object does not contain message field but only id, link and updated time.

What is the correct graph API to get content of the message as well?

I tried conversations and me/conversations:

```
try {
  // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
  $pm = $fb->get('me/conversations', $pagetoken);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All i needed was to turn down graph API version for my app to 2.4 and it worked. only available for apps that were registered at the time when graph API 2.4 was available or before .